# parsing json error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have a problem when parsing json from php to javascript

this is my example code :

```
//function
MethodAjax = function (wsFile, param) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '../proses/' + wsFile + ".proses.php",
        data: 'param='+param,
        error: function (msg) {
            return;
        },
    });
};

//call function 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#getproduk').click(function(){
        var param = {
        ProdukId : '1',
        ProdukName : 'test'
    };

    CallMethodWithAjax('try', JSON.stringify(param)).done(function(data){
        $data =  JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data); 
    });
});

//Simple Php code
<?php
    $data = $_POST['param'];

    $data = (json_decode($data));

    $data1['name'] = $data->ProdukName;
    $data1['id'] = $data->ProdukId;
    $data1['test'] = 'test';


    echo json_encode($data1);
?>

//post, response and error at console
response : {"name":"test","id":"1","test":"test"}
post : param    {"ProdukId":"1","ProdukName":"test"}
error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON  data
```

how to solve this probled, i have try the solution that i found at SO and google, but still cannot solve this problem

please someone help

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function will yield a JavaScript object if the response is JSON so I believe the error you're seeing is a result of trying to parse a JavaScript object and not a string as you're expecting. In the callback you're providing to the `done` function, inspect `data` and you'll find that it's an object and there is no need to `JSON.parse` the result.